# How to add a label based on dense rank value

Tags: t-sql

Is there any way I can reference the inner dense rank results and give them appropriate labels like I am trying to do? It seems like in T-SQL I just can NOT do an "Order by" in an inner query, it is producing an error like:

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

But then how do I attach appropriate labels to the dense rank results in the code below?

```
WITH basequery AS (
         SELECT c.baseentityid,
            c.team,
            c.providerid,
          --  rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c.baseentityid ORDER BY c.version DESC) AS rn,
            t.vaccinedate,
            t.vaccine,
            t.vaccinesource,
            t.num
           FROM vr.child_registration c
             CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (c.bcgsource,c.bcgdate,'bcg',1), (c.opv0source,c.opv0date,'opv0',2), (c.penta1source,c.penta1date,'penta1',3), (c.pcv1source,c.pcv1date,'pcv1',4), (c.rota1source,c.rota1date,'rota1',5), (c.opv1source,c.opv1date,'opv1',6), (c.penta2source,c.penta2date,'penta2',7), (c.pcv2source,c.pcv2date,'pcv2',8), (c.rota2source,c.rota2date,'rota2',9), (c.opv2source,c.opv2date,'opv2',10), (c.penta3source,c.penta3date,'penta3',11), (c.ipvsource,c.ipvdate,'ipv',12), (c.pcv3source,c.pcv3date,'pcv3',13), (c.opv3source,c.opv3date,'opv3',14), (c.measles1source,c.measles1date,'measles1',15), (c.tcvsource,c.tcvdate,'tcv',16), (c.ipv2source,c.ipv2date,'ipv2',17), (c.measles2source,c.measles2date,'measles2',18)) t(vaccinesource, vaccinedate, vaccine, num)
          WHERE t.vaccinedate IS NOT NULL AND t.vaccinedate <> ''
          
        )
 SELECT aa.baseentityid,
    aa.team,
    aa.vaccinedate,
    aa.vaccine,
    aa.vaccinesource,
    aa.num,
    aa.providerid,
    aa.visitrank,
        CASE
            WHEN aa.visitrank = 0 THEN 'external vaccination'
            WHEN aa.visitrank = 1 THEN 'Enrollment'
            ELSE 'Visitation'
        END AS visittype,
        CASE
            WHEN aa.providerid LIKE '%vacc%' THEN 'Vacc'
            ELSE 'Non-Vacc'
        END AS providertype
   FROM ( SELECT a.baseentityid,
            a.team,
            a.vaccinedate,
            a.vaccine,
            a.vaccinesource,
            a.num,
            a.providerid,
                CASE
                    WHEN a.vaccinesource = 'vaccinatoradministered' THEN dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a.baseentityid, (
                    CASE
                        WHEN a.vaccinesource = 'vaccinatoradministered' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END) ORDER BY (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.vaccinedate,111)) )
                    ELSE 0
                END AS visitrank
           FROM basequery a
          WHERE a.rn = 1
          GROUP BY a.baseentityid, a.team, a.vaccinedate, a.vaccine, a.vaccinesource, a.num, a.providerid
          ORDER BY a.baseentityid, a.num) aa;
```

Comment: If you look at the error you'll note it isn't complaining about the `RANK` function you have commented out, it's complaining about your `ORDER BY` clause in your derived table, `aa`. You were already told that you **cannot** `ORDER BY` in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions; both by the error *and* in your prior question.

Comment: I have to include Order by in the derived table in order to get Dense_rank. And then I have to attach labels based on those Dense_rank values.

Comment: *"I have to include Order by in the derived table in order to get Dense_rank."* and that has **nothing** to do with the error.

Comment: **-->`ORDER BY a.baseentityid, a.num) aa;`<--** That is an **`ORDER BY`** inside a **derived table**.

Comment: Also, why does your derived table `aa` have a `GROUP BY`? There's no aggregation in that statement.

Comment: You can also abbreviate `WHERE t.vaccinedate IS NOT NULL AND t.vaccinedate <> ''` to simply `WHERE t.vaccinedate <> ''` due to how `NULL` values work. Though the statement doesn't make much sense if I am honest; what "date" is `''`? This looks like you are storing date and time values as a `varchar` *not* a date and time data type; that is a severe flaw that needs fixing.

Comment: thanks so much! if you add this feedback as an answer, I will accept it as well. Best wishes

Comment: There's no need for me to; the reason for your error was already explained in your prior question.

Comment: Does this additional group by lead to incorrect results? Or will it just add time to query execution?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` will, effectively, lead to an implicit `DISTINCT`; but if you want distinct results, why are you not using `DISTINCT`? A `GROUP BY` is for when you are aggregating the data; you aren't doing that.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help, I appreciate it so much. I wish you have a wonderful week ahead. :)